# How to increase timeout for session If no new command reaches in Nightwatch 2.0

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I have a wait command via API with opened browser and browser closed before condition is set true. How to increase timeout If no new command reaches and what is it name it?
e.g.

```
before(){ 
  loginPage.login(user,pass); 
} 
test(){ 
  simulate.startJob();
  waitUntilJobCompleted() - there is no interaction with browser; 
  ......browser closed 
  page.doSomething() 
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: before(){
   loginPage.login(user,pass);
}
test(){
   simulate.startJob()
   waitUntilJobCompleted() - there is no interaction with browser;

......browser closed

page.doSomething()
}